# Having an issue using Designer 2013 to send emails, Can't publish workflow due to errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm hoping this is an easy problem, but I'm having an issue using SharePoint 2013 designer to send an email.  I'm using "Created By" and a custom field that captures email addresses (separated by semi-colons) to send an email which is populated with other fields from the current item.

I have three steps that require a custom email be sent utilizing this same functionality.  All three steps show up RED when I click "Check workflow for errors" in designer 2013.  I'm currently at a loss as to the reason for the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if there are no email settings configured for your farm.

Open Central Administration => System Settings => Configure outgoing e-mail settings.